# Matrix index notation confusion in physics

Tags: matrices, physics

$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$I'm confused about converting between explicit matrix expressions and index notation. Take $\eta_{\mu\nu}=\diag(-1,1,1,1)$ and $A$ some $4\times4$ matrix. For example,

\begin{align}
& (\diag(-1,1,1,1).A.\diag(-1,1,1,1))^T\\[8pt]
= {} & (\eta_{\mu\rho} A^{\rho\sigma} \eta_{\sigma\nu})^T \\[8pt]
= {} & \eta_{\nu\sigma} A^{\sigma\rho} \eta_{\rho\mu} \\[8pt]
= {} & \diag(-1,1,1,1).A.\diag(-1,1,1,1)
\end{align}
but it's not its own transpose! Which step is wrong? Also,
$$A^\mu{}_\mu=A^{\mu\rho}\eta_{\rho\mu}=A.\diag(-1,1,1,1)$$
but it should be the trace of $A$. How shall we convert between index notation and explicit matrix notation such that every step is mathematically justified and no confusions arise?

Comment: a diagonal matrix is symmetric and is its own transpose. Evidently they are saying that $A$ is also symmetric.

Comment: I'm talking about the case where we are given any $A$. What went wrong?

Comment: How about if you do a 2 by 2 example with actual fixed numbers as entries of $A.$ i can see something that happened here but it seems you are saying that you came up with all this. So, please show us a 2 by 2 example.